# How to ask JQuery load function to load complete page content before moving further

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am using JQuery to load header and footer as shown below. `JQuery("").load` is working only when the code is put after the corresponding `<div id="header">`. I want to load the header.jsp content at the starting of the page may be in `<head>` section or I want browser to first download header.jsp content and move further so that it loads faster.

**This way actually my body is displaying first as it have less content and then header and footer pages are coming. I want to display complete page at once in browser**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="myForm">
        <div id="header" ></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery("#header").load('header.jsp');
        </script>
        <div>
        Body Content goes here..
        </div>

        <div id="footer" ></div>
        <script>
            jQuery("#footer").load('footer.jsp');
        </script>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way we can achieve this functionality.

Comment: Do you know what is the use of <head>??

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#header").load("header.jsp").done(function(){
         $("#footer").load('footer.jsp');
}
```

Comment: The code snippet you shared is not working. 'done' is that a callback function. Is there anyother way? Is there anyway like to pre-load header jsp before body content renders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [load() callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/), first load `hearder` then `content of page` then `footer` like,

**HTML**

```
<form action="myForm">
    <div id="header" ></div>
    <div id="content">
       <!-- Body Content goes here.. -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer" ></div>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     jQuery("#header").load('header.jsp',function(){ // loads header first
         jQuery("#content").load('content.jsp',function(){ // then loading content
            jQuery("#footer").load('footer.jsp');// finally footer
         });
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: loading header and footer jsp's is fine this way. But I don't have content.jsp and I am not ready to move my body into content.jsp.How can I say load my content div tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$(function(){
     jQuery("#header").load('header.jsp',function(){ // loads header first

      jQuery("#content").load('content.jsp',function(){ // then loading content
            jQuery("#footer").load('footer.jsp');// finally footer
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this question over a year ago, but maybe you still need the answer, or maybe it'll help someone else :)

If I understand correctly, you are trying to load the page in sections, from top to bottom, one after another, like this:
- 1. header
- 2. content
- 3. footer

And you want to avoid having `header` load before `content`, and `content` load before `footer`.

### The Problem - AJAX asynchronous loading

The problem here is the very common JavaScript/AJAX asynchronous loading.   The $.load() method you're using is actually just an AJAX call and it takes much longer to complete and return the data you want than the HTML page (`content`) takes to load.  This means your HTML content will always load before these AJAX calls complete and return the `header` and `footer` content.

**But I think I have a solution!**

### Solution

I am adapting @Rohan Kumar's answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     jQuery("#header").load('header.jsp',function(){ // loads header first
         jQuery(window).load(function(){ // then wait for `content` to load
            jQuery("#footer").load('footer.jsp');// finally footer
         });
     });
   });
</script>
```

Since you don't have `content.jsp`, I am suggesting here to use jQuery(window).load(); as that should allow the content enough time to load and b populate the DOM, at which point it'll go and retrieve `footer.jsp`.  Let me know if it works!